# How to Extract filtered objects using lodash or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Hi i have an collection  like this, i am trying to filter the collection,can anybdy help me on this

```
[{
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "Yes",
        "country_name": "India"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "NO",
        "country_name": "India"
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "YES",
        "city_name": "Hubli",
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "country_name": "India"
    },
      {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "YES",
        "city_name": "Bangalore",
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "country_name": "India"
    }]
```

I need an filtered **collection** where **cityname** should present and **permission:"yes",** the output i need is.

Output:

```
[

 {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "YES",
        "city_name": "Hubli",
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "country_name": "India"
    },
      {
        "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
        "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
        "permission": "YES",
        "city_name": "Bangalore",
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "country_name": "India"
    }]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check the wanted constraints.

```js
var array = [{ parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR1", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "Yes", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "NO", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "YES", city_name: "Hubli", state_name: "Karnataka", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "YES", city_name: "Bangalore", state_name: "Karnataka", country_name: "India" }],
    result = array.filter(function (a) {
        return a.city_name && a.permission === 'YES';
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

lodash with [`_.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain) and [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter)

```js
var array = [{ parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR1", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "Yes", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "NO", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "YES", city_name: "Hubli", state_name: "Karnataka", country_name: "India" }, { parent_id: "DISTRIBUTOR2", id: "DISTRIBUTOR3", permission: "YES", city_name: "Bangalore", state_name: "Karnataka", country_name: "India" }],
    result = _
        .chain(array)
        .filter('city_name')
        .filter({ permission: 'YES' });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you are looking for, using [filter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp):

```js
var arr = [{
            "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR1",
            "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
            "permission": "Yes",
            "country_name": "India"
        },
        {
            "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
            "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
            "permission": "NO",
            "country_name": "India"
        },
        {
            "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
            "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
            "permission": "YES",
            "city_name": "Hubli",
            "state_name": "Karnataka",
            "country_name": "India"
        },
          {
            "parent_id": "DISTRIBUTOR2",
            "id": "DISTRIBUTOR3",
            "permission": "YES",
            "city_name": "Bangalore",
            "state_name": "Karnataka",
            "country_name": "India"
        }]
    
    var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
      return item.city_name && item.permission === "YES"
    })
    
    console.log(filtered)
```

Filter takes a function and applies it to each element in the array, if the function returns `true` the item is kept, otherwise it is discarded.